# Controller not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, controller

I've confirmed the post request to the action method in the controller is correct. When I set a breakpoint in the controller, it is not hit. Why is this happening? I believe my HTML is correct as well.

ManageClients.cshtml

```
    @using OPP.Web.ViewModels
@model AdminViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage Clients";
}

<h2>Manage Clients</h2>

<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>Client ID </th>
        <th>Client Name </th>
        <th>Client Expiration Date</th>
        <th>Facility Code</th>
        <th>Client Email</th>
        <th>Is the client Active?</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (Client client in Model.Clients)
    {

        <tr>

            <td>@Html.ActionLink(client.client_id.ToString(), "Index", "Clients", new { id = client.client_id }, null)</td>
            <td>@client.Name</td>
            <td>
                @client.ExpireDate

                @if (client.ExpireDate != null)
                {
                    using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateExpireTime", "Clients"))
                    {
                        <label>Add days (28 is 4 weeks)</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Client.Days, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Client.client_id, new { @Value = client.client_id, @class = "hidden" })
                        @*<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Workouts")'" />*@
                        <input type="submit" value="Update Time" />
                    }
                }
            </td>
            <td>@client.FacilityCode</td>
            <td>@client.Email</td>
            <td>@client.Active</td>
            <td>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Clients"))
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Client.client_id, new { @Value = client.client_id, @class = "hidden" })
                    @*<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Workouts")'" />*@
                    <input type="submit" value="Revoke access" />
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<h2>Manually make a client active (28 day subscription)</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ManualActiveAdd", "Clients",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <label>Client ID:</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Client.client_id, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @*<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Workouts")'" />*@
    <input type="submit" value="Give 4 week access" />

}
```

Clients Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(Client client)
        {
            if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if(User.IsInRole("Superuser"))
                {
                    using(OPPDBContext context = new OPPDBContext())
                    {
                        Client nclient = context.Clients.Where(p => p.client_id == client.client_id).FirstOrDefault();
                        nclient.Active = false;
                        nclient.IsAssessment = false;
                        nclient.IsSurvey = false;
                        nclient.ExpireDate = null;
                        context.Clients.AddOrUpdate(nclient);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("ManageClients", "Admin");
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Error");
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateExpireTime(Client client)
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (User.IsInRole("Superuser"))
                {
                    using (OPPDBContext context = new OPPDBContext())
                    {
                        Client nclient = context.Clients.Where(p => p.client_id == client.client_id).FirstOrDefault();
                        nclient.ExpireDate = nclient.ExpireDate.Value.AddDays(client.Days);
                        context.Clients.AddOrUpdate(nclient);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("ManageClients", "Admin");
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Error");
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ManualActiveAdd(Client client)
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (User.IsInRole("Superuser"))
                {
                    using (OPPDBContext context = new OPPDBContext())
                    {
                        Client nclient = context.Clients.Where(p => p.client_id == client.client_id).FirstOrDefault();
                        nclient.Active = true;
                        nclient.IsAssessment = true;
                        nclient.IsSurvey = true;
                        nclient.ExpireDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(28);
                        context.Clients.AddOrUpdate(nclient);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("ManageClients", "Admin");
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Error");
            return View();
        }
```

If my post request/ controller are correct, what could possibly be the issue?

Comment: you meant after you call your method   you can not stop on break point?

Comment: In my experience, this happens when the model has significant errors in it. Your code is likely failing before the controller is hit. Or, your route to the controller is incorrect. Can you use Postman to confirm that the URL you're posting to is correct?

Comment: You should also include the full controller class, minus any sensitive code, and specify what form / action you're submitting in your cshtml.

Comment: Is the Solution running in `Debug` or `Release` Mode?